# Rust fs::create_dir_all doesn't work on other computers

Tags: windows, rust

`new_file_path` is a generated path, I've excluded the generation logic because on the two computers the generated paths are the same.

```
let new_file_path = "Z:\NUOVO RAPPORTINO ELETTRONICO\2024\1 Gennaio\Name Surname";

match std::fs::create_dir_all(new_file_path) {
    Ok(_r) => {
    
        println!("Creazione cartelle avvenuta con successo!");
        
        //Other things to do if succeeds
      
    },
  
    Err(error) => {
        println!("Errore durante la creazione delle cartelle: {error}");
        println!("GetLastError: {}", unsafe { GetLastError().to_string() });
    },

}
```

This runs fine on my computer, but throws a runtime error on another.

On the other computer, `std::fs::create_dir_all` throws this error: `failed to create whole tree`
and winapi's `GetLastError()` gives me: `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`

The OSs are not the same, mine is Windows 10, the other one is Windows 11, but i don't think that's the problem.

I've compiled it with `cargo build --release`

`Z:\` is a shared network folder on a third computer (Windows 11), but both computer one and two have same permissions

The path `Z:\NUOVO RAPPORTINO ELETTRONICO\2024` already exist, on my computer it generates `\1 Gennaio\Name Surname` in it and then proceed with the other code, on the other one it throws the same errors both if the path "fully" exists (doesn't need to create any folder) or if it needs to create it.

Does anyone have any clue on what's going on?

Comment: You should use the official [`windows`](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs) crate instead of the unsupported `winapi`.

Comment: For `GetLastError()` specifically, you don't need to use any foreign crate, you can (and should) use [`std::io::Error::last_os_error()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.last_os_error).

Comment: Also, the error is already returned, why do you need `GetLastError()`?

Comment: create_dir_all is trying to create each parent directory recursively, and failing to do so. [However](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/fs.rs.html#2558) it also checks explicitly if the path already exists, and if so returns success. Try to create the directory manually and then check the value of `Path::new(new_file_path).is_dir()`, if this is false, then you simply have a permission error. Unfortunately the error "failed to create whole tree" from create_dir_all is totally useless but you already have the real error - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND may happen if you don't have correct permissions.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks for the 'last_os_error()' advice, i used 'GetLastError()' because i did a little bit of research and behind 'std::fs::create_dir_all' there shuld be winapi or something similar, and with 'GetLastError()' i hoped to get some more useful error

Comment: @user2407038 i've tried what you suggested, and it returns false, but i don't get it, permissions are same for both of the computers, and why it allows me to manually create folder from that computer

Comment: @DP1000 I think at this stage there are a lot of potential causes, it definitely seems like a permission issue, and Windows permissions issues can be very hard to solve. You know that your user has permissions for this directory but the rust program does not. Perhaps try to check if you are able to read any files at all on the drive `Z:` ?

Comment: Hi @user2407038 sorry for the delay, i just tried opening a file with the program, and it seems that, even if it has admin rights, it can't open files in Z:

Comment: @user2407038 I have some updates, i tried `Path::new("Z:").try_exists()` here is [try_exists()'s docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.try_exists) and it seems not to be a permission problem, because it gives me `Ok(false)`, so now i'm more confused than before

Comment: @DP1000 Indeed, that's very strange. My next step would be to try to verify that this is not an issue somehow introduced by the rust stdlib specifically, by writing a simple C or C++ program that uses the winap directly to check if the file exists (i.e. using [GetFileAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa)), making sure to invoke the programs the same way (i.e. from the same shell).